# How to Embed InVision Prototype iframe with no background?

Tags: html, css, iframe, background, prototype

I have been trying to embed my prototype from InVision by using an iframe. 
For some reason, mine has a dark background underneath the frame.

I have seen some embedded frames with no background and I would like to have mine displayed this way.

How could I do this?

The prototype embedded on my website:

[image: The prototype embeded on my website]

I want to embed the iframe looking like this:

[image: I want to embed iframe looking like this]

Any help and information will be highly appreciated !

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/smlrolland/vtjajdxv/                I came across this link when searching, and tried copying and pasting this code onto mine, but it shows up with the dark background. :/

Comment: Suggest you to edit the question and add any extra information there instead of writing it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

go to the Inspect window.

Find the line of code that says
"Inherited from [body.branding-invision.embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayw64.png)"

Click on it.

Then find the line that says
"[body.embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nddM4.png) {background:..... .}"

You can change the background colour there.